# Windows 10 screen resolution screwed after updating drivers

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I upgraded my drivers with **DriverPack Solution.** Now my screen resolution is screwed. I can choose only between 1024x768 and 800x600. Also I don't have restore points.

Any idea how to fix it?

My system:

[image: My system]

Comment: I've never heard of DriverPack Solution, I tend to get my drivers from the manufacturer. Have you tried rolling back the drivers in Device Manager? Or checking you have the correct GPU drivers on the AMD website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. I re-download and install the driver. It seems that I shouldn't use such software for dealing with my drivers.